# Get newly installed app from BroadcastReceiver:onReceive

Tags: android

Is there has the way I can get newly installed app from BroadcastReceiver onReceive method.

```
public class PackageAddedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Package Installed: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

I have set the filter as:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.PackageAddedReceiver" android:label="Package added Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So what's the best way to get newly installed Package's info?

Thanks.

Comment: check name if it is not correct android:name=".receiver.PackageAddedReceiver"

Comment: The onReceive can trigger, what I want is to get the NEWLY installed package info.